# Save service data while refreshing page

Tags: angular, spring, session, observable

I have a simple service, that holds user credential ( username and password via btoa ):

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {
  userCredentials = '';
}
```

initializing fileds while loggin in:

```
this.userService.userCredentials =  btoa(this.user.username + ':' + this.user.password);
```

I use this credentials in my backend spring boot app, to authenticate user etc.:

```
@RequestMapping("/core/user")
public Principal user(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String authToken = request.getHeader("Authorization").substring("Basic".length()).trim();
    return () -> new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(authToken)).split(":")[0];
}
```

How to handle page refresh in such way as not to lose data in service?
Holding such data in session storage is very unsafe, so I don't want to store user credential in localStorage/sessionStorage.

Answer (score 3):

You should save your `authToken`, not the userCredentials.
On refresh, make a query to log in with the token.
If it's still valid, you'll retrieve user credentials.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can not do that. You can use `localStorage`, `sessionStorage`, `cookies`, pass them to `queryParams` on reload and get them again or get them by a api call.

No other way.